# SharePoint Filter Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, filter

I want to provide search capabilities for my document library some what similar to as depicted in the following screenshot.

[image]

But the point is I don't want the user to enter anything in the searchbox, rather I want him to select appropriate filters( as the documents are tagged with certain metadata which wish to use in filters).

Though I have tried using refiners for this task but they are available only after a user has done a search. Any help or even suggestions are most welcomed and would be much appreciated.

Also document searched will be based over a combination of multiple filter values, i.e. meta data selected by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head. Create a Result Source with your desired query. For example if it's "everything" use `*`. If it's just the cell phone content type use `ContentType="Cell Phone"`.

Then in your Search web part, change the query to use your Result Source. It will return all results automatically. Then your refiners can be employed.

Most people want to avoid this behavior. In your case it should work just fine.